# How to get rid google chrome helper message pop up

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In macOS, when you set the chromedriver to headless, google chrome helper will pop up an annoying
[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOdEZ.png)

If you close the window, the program will break, if you choose always allow, it will also break, the only way is to let it sit and do nothing while the program is working behind it until it finishes and you're allowed to close this window.

This is so annoying, I want to publish my program and I don't want my mac users to get disturbed by this.

> Use another headless browser instead

nope. No can't do, HTMLUnitDriver javascript engine is useless. PhantomJS and JBrowser? Obsolete, no Java 11 support.

**The window only shows when the chromedriver is headless and on the macOS.**

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of software is this that is a desktop application distributed to end users that needs to use WebDriver with a real Chrome instance? WebDriver is designed for software testing purposes and one would hope that software testers would be technical enough that this wouldn't be a problem for them.

Comment: @DanielPryden Selenium is used for all sorts of automation tasks, including screen-scraping and some monitoring.

Comment: @chrylis: OK. But none of those things sound like things I would expect an end-user desktop application to be doing, with the possible exception of a tool for technical users (where I don't see this being a problem). If you're building an end-user app, it shouldn't need to be doing screen-scraping, it should be using an API.

Comment: @DanielPryden That makes an unwarranted assumption that such an API is available.

Comment: @DanielPryden I wanted to create a program where users click a button, for example, the button is called "how many my stackoverflow inbox"  and it will return the number by obtaining the number from behind the scene in a headless browser.